# Paired t-test with redundant data

Tags: paired-data, research-design

As part of my work I've gathered biological data for a set of (n=3) mice under two conditions ~ treatment and control. Since there is some inherent variability in behavioral research, I collected data from each mouse under both treatment and control on multiple occasions.

For example, consider I'm looking at total distance traveled x. Mouse #A will have a set of data that looks like this:

Mouse #A: x<sub>T<sub>1</sub></sub>, x<sub>T<sub>2</sub></sub>, x<sub>T<sub>3</sub></sub>, x<sub>C<sub>1</sub></sub>, x<sub>C<sub>2</sub></sub>, x<sub>C<sub>3</sub></sub>

Here, the subscripts T and C represent treatment/control, respectively, while the numbers indicate that there's multiple data of each category.

My aim is to test whether there's a statistical difference in x across the two conditions, which inherently brings me to the **paired t-test**. However, for a paired t-test, one only needs a single pair of values (x<sub>T</sub>,x<sub>C</sub>) for each mouse. I wanted to know if there's a way to perform the paired t-test when there's multiple values for each condition.

To elucidate: each of the three mice has three x<sub>T</sub> and x<sub>C</sub> collected. There is some variance in x<sub>T<sub>1-3</sub></sub> and x<sub>C<sub>1-3</sub></sub> for each mouse.

Right now, I only see two solutions to my dilemma. **1)** I choose a random x<sub>T</sub> and x<sub>C</sub> for each mouse to perform the test. **2)** I average x<sub>T<sub>1-3</sub></sub> and x<sub>C<sub>1-3</sub></sub> for each mouse and use the averages to perform the test.

Of course, I think the second option has more merit, although I do not know if it is the right way to handle this scenario, or if there's a better way. I am not statistically inclined. Either way, both options make it so that I reduce the input of the paired t-test from 18 datapoints (6 per mouse) to 6 data points (2 per mouse). I do not find this appealing as it will just artificially drive my p-value up (is this a bad way to think about it?).

What I'm curious to know is if there's a way I could do a paired t-test that includes all 18 data points? Of course, I could pair (x<sub>T<sub>1</sub></sub>, x<sub>C<sub>1</sub></sub>), (x<sub>T<sub>2</sub></sub>, x<sub>C<sub>2</sub></sub>), and (x<sub>T<sub>3</sub></sub>, x<sub>C<sub>3</sub></sub>) together and just add them all to the pile. But then I have 3 pairs of pairs that are nondistinct, as they come from the same mouse. Also, the pairing outlined above is purely arbitrary, as it would make no difference whether x<sub>T<sub>1</sub></sub> gets paired with x<sub>C<sub>1</sub></sub>,x<sub>C<sub>2</sub></sub>, or x<sub>C<sub>3</sub></sub>.

Please let me know what you think! My only option so far is to go with plan (2) mentioned above, but I do not know if it is the correct way or if there's a better way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking at a *mixed effects model* where the random effect is the mouse ID, and the fixed effect is the binary control/treatment status. Your response variable will be the difference: for example $d_{i1} = x_{i1C} - x_{i1T}$ for mouse $i$. The random effect captures the variance from repeated measures on the same mouse.

I am assuming that the first control measurement is actually paired with the first treatment measurement. Not sure if this is actually the case - if there isn't an actual pairing, then the response would just the the $x$ variable rather than the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your input Alex! I've been going back and forth whether to consider the first treatment paired with the first control or not. Certainly, the two data points were obtained closer together than the second pair of treatment/control, so there's a temporal argument to be made. It might be a good idea to do so, as there are certain temporal variables that may be confounding (such as temperature and the animal's circadian rhythm)

Comment: I don't know much about biology, but if you can account for those temporal variables, then certainly go for it!

Answer (score 0):

I simply wanted to respond to Alex's answer about implementing a mixed-effects model by showing how it can be done using the statsmodel package in python (because I don't really use R or MATLAB). This is my sample code with random data...

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.regression.mixed_linear_model import MixedLM

# Create a pandas DataFrame with your data
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Mouse': ['Mouse 836'] * 6 + ['Mouse 837'] * 6 + ['Mouse 897'] * 6,
    'Condition': ['Control'] * 3 + ['Treatment'] * 3 + ['Control'] * 3 + ['Treatment'] * 3 + ['Control'] * 3 + ['Treatment'] * 3,
    'Distance': [10, 12, 15, 8, 9, 11, 14, 16, 13, 7, 6, 9, 11, 13, 10, 12, 14, 15]
})


data.head(18)

# Define the mixed effects model formula
formula = "Distance ~ Condition"

# Fit the mixed effects model
mixed_model = MixedLM.from_formula(formula, data=data, groups=data["Mouse"])
result = mixed_model.fit()

# Print the summary of the model
print(result.summary())
```

I still welcome any additional responses/perspectives. I will be reading more on the mixed-effects model and see exactly how to interpret the result for my own data. Thanks again!